# Lua table of string values as parameter in C function

Tags: c, arrays, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I want to make a C function that takes a lua table with strings as parameter, and the lua table does not have any keys, just values. How can I do this? I cannot figure it out. I did not find anything when I searched in google.

Comment: Did you take a look at Programming in Lua book? Especially the chapter 24

Comment: @hjpotter92 No, I will take a look tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Do you know how tables work in Lua? (hint: they contain key/value pairs, there are no keys without values or values without keys)

Comment: @immibis But they have a default key when you don,t specify one yourself right?

Comment: @ErikW The default keys are consecutive integers starting from 1.

Comment: @immibis 5 then how do you access them from lua_getfield

Comment: @ErikW you don't, because that only works for string keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "default" keys in a table are consecutive integers starting from 1. This:

```
{"hello", "world"}
```

is the same as:

```
{[1] = "hello", [2] = "world"}
```

You cannot access these entries with `lua_getfield`, because that takes a string key. You can do it the "manual" way, with `lua_pushnumber` and `lua_gettable`. If `L` is your `lua_State*`, `t` is the index of the table on the stack and and `k` is the key, then:

```
lua_pushnumber(L, k);
lua_gettable(L, t);
```

should do the same thing as:

```
lua_getfield(L, t, k);
```

does for string keys. Note that if `t` is a relative index (a negative number), then because you're pushing another item onto the stack, you'll need to adjust it by 1.